# Gopuram and Kalasams

Tags: scripture, architecture

We can view a gopuram in any Hindu temple consisting of small statues and kalasams above them. The kalasams will be in odd numbers and will be in gold or copper and placed on the top of the gopuram. It is said that the power to the deity will come from heaven thru this kalasams. An old age saying is gopura darisanam kodi punnyam  ; meaning If a person see the gopura alonngwith kalasams then it will be crores of punya to that person. Any scriptural evidence from Hinduism related ithihasas or puranas.

Comment: @parthassarathy raghavan i also have the same doubt